# How to convert date to milliseconds with out timezone offset?

Tags: java, android, android-date

I what to convert selected date to milliseconds without timezone difference.
Below is my code.

```
 String selectedDate=Jan 18, 2020;
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US);
 Date date = format.parse(selectedDate);
```

while running I am getting date like 
Sat Jan 18 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2020. But I want without timezone difference like Jan 18, 2020.

Comment: `LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(selectedDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US));`

Comment: @YCF_L-  this function is available above SDK 26. For the lower end what needs to do?

Comment: What about using https://www.threeten.org I think It can be better to use it

Comment: On executing what are you getting this long format date? Is it some ```System.out.print()``` call? That is, you have a ```Date``` instance as you have shown in the code. After that, how are you getting this representation of the date?

Comment: Here my problem is GMT time. I need to convert Jan 18, 2020, to milliseconds without adding GMT time.

Comment: But there has to be some timezone, isn't it? Is your question only about getting a formatted string which doesn't have the timezone or is it that you want the ```Date``` object not to have timezone, which is not possible. It will be at least GMT +00:00, I mean.

Comment: @Sree -  Yes, I am getting the Date object with the current timezone. But my requirement is to convert date(Jan 18, 2020) to milliseconds without timezone difference. I don't need time zone differences. Is there is any way possible?

Comment: What do you mean by *without timezone difference*? It’s never the same date in all time zones, so you need to settle on a time zone or offset from UTC for your question to make sense. Do you want the time at the start of the day in UTC, that is, at offset zero (0)?

Comment: I want to represent my birthdate ex. "1990.01.31" not as a string, but as millis. But if I feed these millis back into some java class that handles time, it might spew out a date that is 1 day ahead or behind, due to timezone bullshit. We want to NOT be affected by timezones. Afterwards we want to transform those millis back to "1990.01.31", we want to get the same string back that we passed in before conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a difference of 0 from UTC:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String selectedDate = "Jan 18, 2020";
    ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.parse(selectedDate, dateFormatter)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(zdt);
    long millisSinceEpoch = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(millisSinceEpoch);
```

Output from this snpipet is:

> ```
> 2020-01-18T00:00Z
> 1579305600000
> ```

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The classes that you used, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, are poorly designed and long outdated, and no one should use them anymore.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.